# System.Collections.Generic

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, generics, dictionary

At the moment, I have a main folder which has 320 sub folders and I'm saving those folder names into to sql server DB in a temporarytable. Then I retrieve that data, consume it, and then delete it.

To pullout folder names I use:

```
`List<string> FolderInfoList = Directory.GetDirectories(stringFolderPath).ToList();`
```

My temporary tablehas 2 columns (ID, Name), of which ID is an auto increment field.

Then I save name detail into a second table which will be resulted

[image]

After that I retrieve each and every folder name using the id, I use and I will delete after using it.

Since my manager requested me to not to use database, I need to find an alternative solution. I know there is a way using Dictionary function but I don't know how to use it or how to assign a unique id for an individual folder name or when I retrieve all the folders name List function, I retrieve them as a list, not individually. I need to manipulate same function using any alternative method.

Comment: Why do you need id to retrieve the folder? Is it stored somewhere?

Comment: Why do you need to assign individual IDs to the folder names? Different objects in the C# runtime already have an implicit different identity. The index at which they're stored at in a plain `List<string>` would also work. (I hope you're not asking how to use `List`s or `Dictionaries` here, that's very much a "read the tutorials" question.)

Comment: `GetDirectories` should already return unique folder names, since you can't have multiple folders with the same name in the same location.  I don't see why you need a unique ID, especially since you don't appear to be accessing folders in multiple directories (or even storing which directory your folders are contained in).  Why don't you just iterate through `FolderInfoList` and perform your actions on the folder names in that collection?  You might want to look into `DirectoryInfo` if you're manipulating the folders or looking at their contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try the following... it will then assign a unique guid for each folder stored in a new class for you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

namespace zielonka.co.uk.stackoverflow.com.samples.unique
{
    class Program
    {
        public class info
        {
            public string name;
            public Guid uniqueID;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> FolderInfoList = Directory.GetDirectories("c:\\").ToList();
            List<info> uniqueFolders = new List<info>();
            foreach (var VARIABLE in FolderInfoList)
            {
                uniqueFolders.Add(new info(){name = VARIABLE, uniqueID = new Guid()});
            }
            foreach (var uniqueFolder in uniqueFolders)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(uniqueFolder.uniqueID+" "+uniqueFolder.name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ToDictionary()` method on a collection - you just need to define the "key" value for the dictionary.

Can you use the index of the item in the list?

```
List<string> folderInfoList = 
    Directory.GetDirectories(stringFolderPath).ToList();

Dictionary<int,string> dict = 
    folderInfoList.ToDictionary(i => i , folderInfoList.IndexOf(i));
```

or a guid (knowing that the Guids will be different each time you run, even if the `Name` is the same:

```
Dictionary<string,string> dict = 
    folderInfoList.ToDictionary(i => i , Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to identify the directroywith a unique ID key. But all your folders come from the same parent directory. Then, the names are unique. No need to create another key.

If you really want to, you can use a simple int counter, or for a more general purpose, a GUID which is provided by the framework, and could be efficient if you need to list directories form multiple heterogeneous sources.